# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll The remote server returned an error: (429)

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

it basically makes several API calls and parses the json results...

```
    public static bool IsOnTheAir(string id)
    {
        string url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/on_the_air";

        int pages = 1;

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(url);

        // first page
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

            pages = int.Parse(jObject["total_pages"].ToString());

            foreach (var show in jObject["results"])
            {
                if (show["id"].ToString() == id) { return true; }
            }
        }

        // subsequent pages
        if (pages > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/on_the_air" + "&page=" + i.ToString();

                stream = webClient.OpenRead(url);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

                    foreach (var show in jObject["results"])
                    {
                        if (show["id"].ToString() == id) { return true; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and now i'm receiving a 429 error on line:

stream = webClient.OpenRead(url)

the error occurs on page 6 every time.

any ideas on how to fix this?

after doing some research, it appears 429 errors are resultant from too many requests.

Comment: Put a delay in so that it so that it waits between request and see if that solves it.

Comment: that works but makes the application run too slow. it's very odd, this never used to be an issue. is there another way I can make the request to appear new? like scramble the ip or something?

Comment: If you scramble the IP then you won't get the response back, as it won't know what IP to send it too.  So no you can't do that.  Check what the rate limitation is of that site and adjust your delay accordingly.  The rate at that site is 30 requests every 10 seconds per IP

Comment: If you are doing that many request you may have to re-engineer how you do things.